# how to assign image for Parent node and child nodes in treeview from assigned imagelist in c#?

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a TreeView and an associated ImageList. What are the steps to add images to the Parent and child nodes ?

All the nodes are being added from the code. Nothing is done from the Design.

```
public void fill_tree()
        {
            host_listbox_new.Items.Clear();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, host_config> hlitem in host_list)
            {
                string sitem = hlitem.Key;
                if (host_list[sitem].sessionOptions == null)
                    host_list[sitem].sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
                host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.Protocol = Protocol.Sftp;
                host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.HostName = host_list[sitem].ip;
                host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.UserName = host_list[sitem].username;
                host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.Password = host_list[sitem].password;
                host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.PortNumber = Convert.ToInt32(host_list[sitem].port);
                //host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = host_list[sitem].rsa;

                if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
                {
                    treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(hlitem.Key.ToString());

                }
                else 
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(hlitem.Key.ToString());
                }



            }
        }

private void Parent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            read_process_config();
            read_host_config();
            host_listbox.Items.Clear();
            treeView1.BeginUpdate();
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("Servers");
            fill_tree();
            treeView1.EndUpdate();
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
            connect_server_bttn.Enabled = false;

        }
```

i want to add items i.e child nodes to **Server** Parent node each of them having one image before them ( green image if `hlitem.Value.connected` is `true`. red image if `hlitem.Value.connected` is `false`)

But i have no idea about treeview or imagelist.
Can anyone help me about the whole thing?

Comment: Prefix the `..Nodes.Add..` commands with `TreeNode tn =  ` Then you can assign an ImageIndex like this: `tn.ImageIndex = 0;`

Comment: did not get you. Can you write it elaborately? @TaW

Answer (score 0):

The Add command returns a reference to the new Node. You can use it to style the Node.
Change your code to this:

```
if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
{
    TreeNode tn =treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(hlitem.Key.ToString());
    tn.ImageIndex = yourIndex;

}
else 
{
    TreeNode tn =treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(hlitem.Key.ToString());
    tn.ImageIndex = yourIndex;
}
```

Or whatever logic you need to set the index.

If you need the parent node's index you could write:

```
tn.ImageIndex = tn.Parent.ImageIndex;
```

You may also want ot check out the other formats of the Add method. Some let you include the ImageIndex directly. You can also include the SelectedIndex; especially if you **don't** want that you should include it to prevent the Tree using its default SelectedIndex!

This will set the node to show the 2nd image, whether selected or not:

```
TreeNode tn =treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(sitem, sitem, 1,1 );
```

Since you can't set a property of an object before you have created it, you can't set the Child nodes when you create the parent node. Instead you can use a simple function to do the changes:

```
void copyImgIndexToChildren(TreeNode tn)
{
    if (tn.Nodes.Count > 0) 
        foreach (TreeNode cn in tn.Nodes) cn.ImageIndex = tn.ImageIndex;
}

void copyImgIndexToAllChildren(TreeNode tn)
{
    if (tn.Nodes.Count > 0)
        foreach (TreeNode cn in tn.Nodes)
        {
            cn.ImageIndex = tn.ImageIndex;
            copyImgIndexToAllChildren(cn);
        }
}
```

The first method changes the direct ChildNodes only , the 2nd recursively changes all levels below the starting node.

BTW: Is there a reason to use `hlitem.Key.ToString()` in your code instead of `sitem`?

Comment: what is the ImageIndex Property of the treeview1? there is an image selected from the collection of imageList1. All the items are showing the same image.

Comment: Yes, it is the index into your `ImageList`. I assume you have it assigned to the TreeView? Each __Node__ has this property, not the TreeView itself. You need to set it for each Node according to your logic.

Comment: they are same, **hlitem.Key.ToString()** and **sitem**

Comment: all the nodes(parent as well as child) are showing the image that is set in the ImageIndex Property (where ImageIndex is 1) of the treeview. and when am selecting any one of them, that particular item is showing another image stored at ImageIndex 0. imagelist has two images at 0 and 1.

Comment: You can set both a default image and a default selected image for the whole tree. These will show if the Nodes don't have their own ImageIndex and SelectedImageIndex set. So if each Node should always show one of your two images you need to set the ImageIndex for each node. If any node should sometimes show no image you need to include an emtpy image in the ImageList. If upon selecting a node no different Image should show you will need to set the SelecteIndex to the same Value as ImageIndex.

Comment: how to set every child node's own ImageIndex and SelectedImageIndex?

Comment: It really depends on __when__ you know the index you want to set. If you know it when you create the child simply incude it in the Add method or style it like I suggested. If you only know about it later, well then change it later, depending on your logic! See me edits!

Comment: the image problem has been solved. Actually i have chaned my listview control to a treeview control. Now there was a method in the listview's SelectedIndexChanged Event. But i dont find any SelectedIndexChanged event in TreeView Events. Can you help me regarding this? @TaW

Comment: Your question was about TreeViews from the biginning, wasn't it?? There is a BeforeSelect and an AfterSelect event in a TreeView.